# Compiling RiccatiSolve LQRegulator gains

Tags: functions, compile, control-systems, code-generation

Given some specific matricies, numA, numB, numP, q and r to calculate LQR gains, one can use simply `LQRegulatorGains` or solve the same via `RiccatiSolve`:

```
Inverse[r].(numB\[Transpose].RiccatiSolve[{numA, numB}, {q, r, matP}] + matP\[Transpose])
```

Giving the stated matricies some values, gains can be calculated and present the same solution as the aformentions `LQRegulatorGains`

I am attempting to compile either one of these functions for external use in embeddedhardware to adaptively calculate new gains on the fly but am completely overwhelmed in its generation. As far as I've come to understand not all code can be compiled and there are few and far between examples of higher level functions being compiled.

Is this possible? How would one give Compile matrices as a variable to be updated frequently for the given function?

Test matricies:

```
{numA, numB, numC, numD}={{{0,1,0},{113.116,-2.45364,0.00808392},{-113.116,2.45364,-0.136792}},{{0},{-15.4569},{261.555}},{{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}},{{0},{0},{0}}}
matP = {{0}, {0}, {0}}
q = DiagonalMatrix[{50, 1, 0.001}];
r = 2 {{1}};
```

Answer (score 1):

[`LQRegulatorGains`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LQRegulatorGains.html) are typically computed offline before deployment and, if need be, some kind of gain scheduling is implemented to handle parameter variations. Also stuff involving matrix operations like Kalman filters and MPC have techniques like sequential Kalman filtering and explicit computations to circumvent doing the matrix computations online.

And a quick google search did not  turn up anything promising for matrix operations on AVR microcontrollers. I found [this](https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/how-do-matrix-mathematics-avr) from about 10 years ago,

IMO, you need to try some gain scheduling approach, and if that will not work it needs to be attempted on the [RasPi](https://www.wolfram.com/raspberry-pi/) which will slow things down.

Comment: Mmm, would you mind showing an example of gain scheduling with mma for use with Microcontrollerkit? That would be equally as helpful...as a side question but just so I know, is it possible to compile the functions riccatisolve or Lqregulatorgains, but just slow to use, or not possible at all. ? Thanks regardless for the info! :)

Comment: You can see a case of gain scheduling using [`Which`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Which.html) and [`NonlinearStateSpaceModel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearStateSpaceModel.html) [here](https://wolfram.com/xid/0ff5lb0ualw71xx16oj8d2l722wxyjs2pl9b3l1ma) which is part of a larger example.

Comment: I don't want to write in absolutes, but as I mentioned [`RiccatiSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RiccatiSolve.html) and [`LQRegulatorGains`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LQRegulatorGains.html) are offline techniques that it is practically certain that no effort will be made to make them compilable for deployment to an embedded target.

Comment: thank you for the links and infos. Just to be clear, I didn't mean compiling specifically to microcontrollers, rather, just using those commands in general with compile. If it's not possible to export to embedded systems, I will try with gain scheduleing and attempt to compile those commands for use in a different software instead....assuming it's possible.